# value just after a string and before <br> in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I have a string like this:

> `Error=0,0<br>Federal withhold=1.00<br>FICA=0.00<br>Medicare=0.00<br>Federal Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>State withhold=361.32<br>State Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>City withhold=0.00<br>City Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>City Resident withhold=0.00<br>City Resident Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>County withhold=0.00<br>County Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>School withhold=0.00<br>School Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>SDI withhold=0.00<br>SDI employer withhold=0.00<br>SUI employer withhold=0.00<br>Version=2013.01,1.02<br>No messages`

From this string i want to extract the value of `State withhold` which is actually `361.32`.

I have this string in c# string , i have tried with `IndexOf` and `Substring` but not able to get how can i get the value till there is `<br>` after that particular word `State withhold`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(
                input.Split("<br>")
                .Where(x => x.StartsWith("State withhold"))
                .First().Split('=').ToArray()[1]);
```

Comment: yes that is originally and still with <br> some one edited that question .

Answer (score 5):

Use the regex `State withhold=([^<]+)<` and read the the value from `Match().Captures[1]`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "Error=0,0<br>Federal withhold=1.00<br>FICA=0.00<br>Medicare=0.00<br>Federal Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>State withhold=361.32<br>State Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>City withhold=0.00<br>City Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>City Resident withhold=0.00<br>City Resident Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>County withhold=0.00<br>County Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>School withhold=0.00<br>School Supplemental withhold=0.00<br>SDI withhold=0.00<br>SDI employer withhold=0.00<br>SUI employer withhold=0.00<br>Version=2013.01,1.02<br>No messages ";

var result = s.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(x=>x.Split('=')[0]=="State withhold").Select(x=>x.Split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `char` is a digit: `char.IsDigit(c)`

When you have the index of 'State withhold' you can go from there:

```
string afterThis = "State withhold";
int i = myString.IndexOf(afterThis) + afterThis.Length;
string tmpString = String.Empty;
while(char.IsDigit(myString.charAt(i)) || char.Equals('.'))
{
    tmpString += myString.charAt(i); // save it to a temp string
    i++;
}
double value = double.Parse(tmpString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex should help...

```
(?<=State\swithhold=).*?(?=\<br\>)
```